# Silverlight ria domain service not being called

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, ria

Hi Im using silverlight ria services and trying to called a domain service method

the domain service class signature goes like this   public class UserDomainService : DomainService

and I have a simple operation to return data

public IQueryable  GetUsers()
        {
         return   userService.GetAll()
                ).AsQueryable();

```
    }
```

this compiles fine an a silverlight proxy is generated on the silverlight client side

how ever when makeing calls from silverlight eg

LoadOperation op = UserDomainContext.Load(UserDomainContext.GetUsers(),UserLoadedCallback,null);

```
        int i = op.Entities.Count();
```

i is always 0,  the domain servcice method is never hit when i put a breakpoint, please help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not have enough detailed code to see the exact problem.

Have you put [EnableClientAccess()] on the service class?

The proxy must be generated because it must be compiling to run.

Hope it helps